How to solve the problem "Fortran Error! mpi_init() could not be located"
I am installing OpenCAEPoro(https://github.com/OpenCAEPlus/OpenCAEPoro_ASC2024).
But I get an error when installing the 4th package(PETSC-3.19.3):
ERROR PICTURE
This is my "build-petsc.sh". $ROOT_DIR is the dir of OpenCAEPoro.
export PETSC_DIR=$ROOT_DIR/petsc-3.19.3
export PETSC_ARCH=petsc_install

./configure CC=mpiicc CXX=mpiicpc \
    --with-fortran-bindings=0 \
    --with-hypre-dir=$ROOT_DIR/hypre-2.28.0/install \
    --with-debugging=0 \
    COPTFLAGS="-O3" \
    CXXOPTFLAGS="-O3" \


make -j 20 PETSC_DIR=$ROOT_DIR/petsc-3.19.3 PETSC_ARCH=petsc_install all
make all check  

MPI seems to be OK.
$ which mpiicc
/opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.11/bin/mpiicc
$ which mpiicpc
/opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.11/bin/mpiicpc
$ which icc
/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.0.0/linux/bin/intel64/icc
$ which icpc
/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.0.0/linux/bin/intel64/icpc
$ which mpiifort
/opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.11/bin/mpiifort
$ which ifort
/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.0.0/linux/bin/intel64/ifort

I really want to know what the problem is. Thanks a lot!

Did you look at the configure.log file it generated or the python line(s) that reported the error. Those should give you a clue.

Just a guess... Intel/mpi installed under /opt/intel/oneapi/mpi. There should probably be include and lib* subdirectories under that have .h files and .so files for mpi. How does petsc know to look there (e.g. a config option)? Or should Intel fortran "just find them"? You may want to manually rerun the make without -j and some verbose option to have it print the detailed commands

Try passing FC=mpiifort

I have solved it! The problem is that I didn't pass parameter**--with-fc**. In this project, I should pass ""--with-fc=0"". I don't know why Readme.md doesn't tell me about this.
